# Sensible way to write function prototypes

Tags: c, dry

I'm looking for a (clean) way of writing a function definition and a function prototype without code duplication. Since DRY is well established as a good idea and hand coding prototypes in header files is a clear violation this seems like a reasonable requirement.

The example code below indicates a (crude) way of solving the problem with the preprocessor. It seems unlikely to be optimal, but does appear to work correctly.

Using separate files and duplication:

```
foo.h:
#ifndef FOO_H
  #define FOO_H
  // Normal header file stuff
  int dofoo(int a);
#endif /* FOO_H */

foo.c:
#include "foo.h"
int dofoo(int a) {
  return a * 2;
}
```

Using the C preprocessor:

```
foo.h:
#ifndef FOO_H
  #define FOO_H

  // Normal header file stuff

  #ifdef PROTOTYPE // if incorrect:
  // No consequences for this test case, but we lose a sanity check
    #error "PROTOTYPE set elsewhere, include mechanism will fall over"
  #endif

  #define PROTOTYPE // if incorrect:
  // "error: redefinition of 'dofoo'" in clang & gcc, 
  // referring to int dofoo() line in foo.c
    #include "foo.c"
  #undef PROTOTYPE //if incorrect:
  // No warnings, but should trigger the earlier #error statement if
  // this method is used in more than one file

#endif /* FOO_H */

foo.c:
#include "foo.h"

int dofoo (int a)
#ifdef PROTOTYPE // if incorrect:
// "error: redefinition of 'dofoo'" in clang & gcc, 
// referring to int dofoo() line in foo.c
  ;
#else
  {
    return a * 2;
  }
#endif
```

The mechanism is a bit odd - the .h file doesn't conventionally include the .c file! The include guard halts the recursion. It compiles cleanly and looks reasonable when run through a standalone preprocessor. Otherwise though, embedding preprocessor conditionals throughout the source doesn't look great.

There are a couple of alternative approaches I can think of.

1. Don't worry about the code duplication
2. Change to a language which generates the interface automatically
3. Use a code generator (e.g. sqlite's makeheaders)

A code generator would work but seems overkill as a solution for a minor annoyance. Since C has been around for somewhere over 25 years at this point there's hopefully a community consensus on the best path to take.

Thank you for reading.

edit: Compiler warnings with gcc 4.8.2 and clang 5.1
Messing up the macro statements produces fairly coherent compiler error messages. Missing an #endif (easily done if the function definition is long) produces "error: unterminated #else" or "error: unterminated conditional directive", both referring to the #ifdef line.

Missing #else means the code is no longer valid C. gcc "error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token" and clang adds "expected function body after function declarator". Both point to the correct line number, but neither suggest an #else is missing.

Spelling PROTOTYPE wrong produces coherent messages if the result is fatal and no warning if the result doesn't matter. The compiler warnings aren't quite as specific as they can be when definition and declaration differ, but they're probably specific enough.

Comment: This looks like a lot of work for zero gain.  You're taking [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) to an unreasonable extreme.

Comment: Odd, but clever. Still, I'm not sure I'd do it in practice.

Comment: It's arguable if this is a violation of DRY, as one of the main motivations for it (if you have the same code twice, you have a bug, forget to fix it in the code duplicate, so the bug is not fixed) don't hold: A change in only one part of the code will be caught by the compiler.

Comment: From DRY perspective, the second approach is worse: There are 4 times you can get `PROTOTYPE` wrong.

Comment: I was surprised that the main concern is about mistakes in the macro commands. Both gcc 4.8.2 and clang 5.1 catch the resulting fatal errors with no warning flags enabled, much as they would catch out of date prototypes. So there doesn't seem to be a decrease in safety. I mostly don't like this method because it's aesthetically unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generally accepted path is your option 1), to not worry and just write the declaration twice.

The repetition coming from prototypes is only a small percentage compared to the function implementations. Macro hacks like in your question quickly become unwieldy and provide little gain. The macro machinery ends up being just as much code as the original prototypes, only that it's now much harder to understand what's going on and that you'll get more cryptic error messages. The trivial to understand duplication gets replaced by about the same amount of much harder to understand trickery.

With normal prototypes the compiler will issue warnings when things don't match up, with such a macro base solution you get hard to understand errors if you forget an `#endif` or something else doesn't match up. For example any mention of `foo.c` in an error might be with or without `PROTOTYPE` defined.

Comment: Compiler warnings seem to be sufficient in either case. The general advice that it's not worth the bother is pretty convincing though. Cheers

Comment: Except [Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43395103/equivalent-of-error-static-declaration-of-function-follows-non-static-decla) doesn't care about an inconsistency with static and extern. It's so irritating how it cannot even give me a warning, but for the same mistake in gcc it is an error!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to take a look at it from another point of view. As I like to see DRY principle, it is meaningful for the code that provides logic, not taking it as repeating strings literally.

This way it would not touch declarations, as they introduce no logic. When you see few pieces of code, that *do* (as in perform some task) the same, just arguments change, then it should be avoided/refactored.

And this is what you actually do. You just introduced some new pre-processing logic into code, i.e. `#ifdef PROTOTYPE... #else ... #endif`, that you will repeat over and over just changing the prototype and the body. If you could wrap it up into something that does not enforce to repeat the branch I'd say it is somewhat ok.

But currently you really do repeat some logic in code, just to eliminate a multiple declarations, which is basically harmless in the context you provide. If you forget something the compiler will tell you something is mismatched. It's c.

I'd say your proposed approach violates it more, than repeated declarations.