# Equivalent of: "error: static declaration of ‘function’ follows non-static declaration" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've been burned a few times where I've changed an extern function to static, and I forgot to delete the header file declaration. The application successfully compiles in Visual Studio, but fails to compile in gcc on Linux.

Forgetting to delete function reference(s) (in other C files) is not a problem, as this will lead to a linker error. The problem is forgetting to delete declaration(s).

For example:

```
file.h:
extern int func(void);

file.c:
int func(void)
{
}
```

If I wish to make that static, in order to narrow its scope to only file.c. I can add the static keyword and then forget to the delete the declaration in the header file:

```
file.h:
extern int func(void); /* forgot to delete */

file.c:
static int func(void) /* compile error in gcc ... static follows non-static */
{
}
```

This leads to:

```
file.c:20: error: static declaration of ‘func’ follows non-static declaration
../include/file.h:459: error: previous declaration of ‘func’ was here
```

I compile mostly on Windows. I don't see a warning or error in Visual Studio 2010. I will be switching to 2015 or 2017 soon.

Is there any equivalent warning or error for this in Visual Studio? I would like to make it an error. I've used the #pragmas below, for example, to change some warnings to errors, which are errors in gcc, but warnings in Visual Studio. In general I want all the compilers for the project to be as strict as each other:

```
/* warning C4027: function declared without formal parameter list */
#pragma warning(error : 4027)
/* warning C4029: declared formal parameter list different from definition */
#pragma warning(error : 4029)
/* warning C4020: 'func' : too many actual parameters */
#pragma warning(error : 4020)
```

Comment: How did you get burned? i.e. what happens in VS when you do this and then call `func` from another unit?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is specifically it successfully compiles in Visual Studio, but then fails to compile in gcc. It's not a problem in the long run, because there are automated nightly builds, and I will notice anyway. I could also manually compile on Linux, remotely. It's just my workstation is Windows, and 99% of my compiling is on Windows, and so this catches me off guard. I want it to fail earlier, so I can fix it earlier.

Comment: VS is a bit notorious as the only widely-used C implementation that is non-conforming, but this is not one of its areas of nonconformance.  All versions of the standard specify that "If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined."  Implementations are not obligated to emit errors or even warnings about undefined behavior, and they may even provide reliable implementation-specific semantics.

Comment: I wrote a feature request here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/393763/improve-compile-error-c2375-redefinition-different.html

Answer (score 0):

I can think of no way to fix this problem in VS. I could understand the test team wanting code that compiles without errors.

Then maybe, as a last step before delivering the code to the test team, run gcc over it as a last check for clean compilation.

Answer (score 0):

```
cl /Za file.c
```

`/Za` disables VC-specific extensions. Don't leave home without it.

```
file.c
file.c(20) : error C2375: 'func' : redefinition; different linkage
        ..\include\file.h(459) : see declaration of 'func'
```

Comment: Wow. I like the concept, but absolutely everything failed to compile, and cl.exe itself crashed!

Comment: Oh yes I recall that Windows headers fail to compile with /Za because Microsoft likes to use their own extensions in public headers. So if you need stricter checks, no winapi for you.